# How to delete unwanted google suggestions on an external site?

Tags: google-chrome, virtualbox, auto-form-fill

I understand if I am on www.google.com, it knows the previous searches or suggestions. This question is NOT about that.

The problem is I am on external website for example here on VirtualBox [website](https://www.virtualbox.org/report/1) but if I click in the search box in top right, it pops up four entries (as in suggestions) which appears to be old google searches but they are not even the most recent ones.

How can I stop these popup suggestions given I am on a non-google website? There is no option in the edit box to delete them? Can I search for these particular "suggestions" and delete them so at least they don't appear?

See attached. The search suggestions doesn't even make sense to me like almost I haven't search them that way but it pops up.

[image]

Comment: This may be a function of your browser. Simply highlighting the entries you wish to remove and clicking your Delete key should work in most cases. Have you tried this yet?